# Apply function from column to other column, efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3], 'f': [lambda x: x + 1,
                                       lambda x: x ** 2, 
                                       lambda x: x / 5]})
```

I'd like to apply 'f' to each 'x' into a new column 'y'. The way I do it now is using apply, but this is a bit slow. Is there a better way? Is storing lambdas in DataFrames a bad idea?

```
df['y'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['f'](row['x']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Just how many functions do you actually have??

Comment: @alkasm One for each row

Comment: Yes, but how many rows? I'm just asking as you don't likely have 500k hardcoded lambdas so I don't see why performance is particularly relevant. Also, this doesn't particularly sound like a good use-case for Pandas.

Comment: @alkasm Around a million. They're not hard-coded.

Comment: How many unique lambdas do you have?

Comment: Then how many unique ones? Or are they actually based on something (row number, some columns, etc) that you can exploit for vectorization?

Comment: I think in this case it would be more useful to show us the problem that lead to this question in the first place.

Comment: @IanS I need to fit an N-dimensional data set with user-defined curves (the lambdas). Some dimensions are independent of each other, so the fitting is to be done for each dimension separately. Hence the reason behind the high number of unique lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is storing lambdas in DataFrames a bad idea?

I think yes, because pandas working efficient with scalars only.

---

If use loop in list comprehension, it is faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3], 'f': [lambda x: x + 1,
                                       lambda x: x ** 2, 
                                       lambda x: x / 5]})

#3k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [97]: %timeit df['y'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['f'](row['x']), axis=1)
104 ms ± 3.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [98]: %timeit df['y1'] = [f(x) for f, x in zip(df['f'], df['x'])]
3 ms ± 93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
#300k
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
In [102]: %timeit df['y'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['f'](row['x']), axis=1)
10.3 s ± 315 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [103]: %timeit df['y1'] = [f(x) for f, x in zip(df['f'], df['x'])]
318 ms ± 4.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Would you have another idea on how to store (and apply) different functions for different column values?

Comment: @foxpal - Hard question, because still need loops, so slow... There is for each row different function?

Comment: Thanks - I wonder why list comprehension is faster. I thought `apply` was meant to be the fastest way to iterate through a DataFrame

Comment: @foxpal - I think there are some checking, also apply is more general like `list comprehension`, so it is reason in my opinion.